# how to split duble value in tow rows in excel

Tags: excel

Hello in my excel sheet i have two same value in one cell. I want to split them. for ex:

```
Cell A                                    | Cell B       | Cell C
===============================================================
my name is demo my name is demo user      |my name is demo|my name is demo user
----------------------------------------------------------------
my first name my first name and last name | my first name |my first name and last name
```

I have tried text to columns tool but not got luck. Any idea about this thanks.

Comment: What is the logic for splitting the first column the way you did it?

Comment: like in above ex;, i want to splitting column when first word repeat my sheet have users first name and again full name in same cell so i want to splitting first name and full name hope you understand . thanks

Comment: You will probably have to use VBA for this.  It might not be easily doable in Excel.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks you . but i dont much know about vba code

Comment: @banme I would agree with Tim, unless you are absolutely certain that splitting on the first word is what you want.  It looks like splitting on the first phrase, that can be repeated, would better describe your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first formula in B1:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)),A1,LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)))+1)-1))
```

This finds the second occurrence of the first word and splits on the character before that.

The second formula in C1:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,B1,"",1))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The solution might fail if the first word is repeated within the first phrase. (Unless he **really** wants to split on the first recurrence of the first word). Try `my first name is not my last my first name is not my last name demo user`  I would think it should split after the first `last` and not after the first `not`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld from his comment above `i want to splitting column when first word repeat` This is why I did it the way I did.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Yes, I see that.  And now I also see, from one of his comments,  that the examples he posted are probably not anything like his real data.  His real data may be more like `Scott Scott Craner` and `Ron Ron Rosenfeld`.  So your solution would seem ideal.